# gwt using guice - bootstrapping or what happens on deployment

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, guice, web-deployment

i have an gwt app that uses guice on server side. all is running fine and i never bothered what happens on deployment time (keep the guice magic magic). the log says that much is done on deployment (i read around a bit and it seems that all bound singletons are instantiated, is this true?). on an webapp there is no main where all begins :-(.

but now i need control over the bootstrapping on deployment: i need to do some checks and if this checks fail i hav to stop deployment - throw an exception and log it (with an appropriate message).

So how does the guice-deployment work and how to control it. is there a way to say: instantiate this before that.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java EE applications (like GAE) you usually do things like that in the `contextInitialized` method of a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that you declare in your web.xml. If you encounter an erroneous condition you could throw an exception out of that method which will prevent the web application container from starting you app.

Comment: thx, in my case i extend "GuiceServletContextListener" and there is indeed a contextInitialized method that could be overwritten. but how to use it correctly? are all injections available at this moment? or could i inject stuff in this method? Or when is the other overwritten method called: getInjector()?